# export drivers before reformatting and re-installing Windows

Tags: windows, drivers

In the past, I've always had to download the drivers for my computers, after I do a reformat and a re-install of Windows.  Is there a quick and dirty way to export all of the drivers in Windows before doing a disk reformat and reinstall of Windows, so that I can just perform an import of all of the drivers, after Windows is back up?  Or is this wishful thinking?  If that is NOT an option and you know of any tricks to accomplish this the easiest way, let me know.

I haven't decided which version of Windows to install, so as long as your answer is for Windows 7 or later, that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the location of all drivers windows has built-in.

C:\windows\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository

The folders are write protected, and it is difficult to modify them directly.

Booting from the windows DVD you can get to a command prompt.
From there:

Assuming d:\drivers contains the folder from above it should import them

Dism /Image:C:\windows /Add-Driver /Driver:d:\drivers /Recurse /ForceUnsigned

after rebooting the drivers should be available to windows.  You may or may not have to go into the device manager and select update driver on each one.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to do this.  The only two drives I had available were the hard drive and CD rom.  Next time, I'll have to burn these files on a CD rom after I reformat C:\.  I won't be able to mark as answered until it's been confirmed.  What I ended up doing is found the wifi driver on Dell's website for my service tag, and burned that to a CD.  After I installed Windows, I installed that wifi driver from the burned CD, and then I could get on the internet to download the rest of the drivers.